# How to get Current User in Sharepoint site workflow 2010?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, workflow

Am trying to find the current logged user in sharepoint site workflow 2010 while creating a project. Based on the user, I would like to retrieve the current user's project manager. Every time am trying to retrieve current user name, it's giving **System Account**.

I even tried logging in as different user but still displaying **System Account** as the current user.

I tried following options :

```
SPUser user = workflowProperties.OriginatorUser;

SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;


SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;

 SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

But everything failed. Am sure that am doing something wrong. I don't know the correct procedure. Some procedures give me null or Object reference not set to an instance of the object or System Account details. I have even tried using elevated permission and its giving me null value.

```
SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated elevatedSubmit = new SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(delegate
        {
            //SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
            //string strAssignedTo = user.Name;

            string sspURL = "http://localhost/PWA/default.aspx";
            SPSite site = new SPSite(sspURL);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPUser theUser = web.CurrentUser;
            string strUserName = theUser.Name;
        });

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(elevatedSubmit);
```

Am I supposed to add users explicitly as SPUser or any other changes before trying to retrieve current user via workflow ?

Comment: question , is this being done from a web page..? if so why not get at the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`by doing 
var user = `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`; if it returns an string like \\Domain\username then run a Split('\\') on the user and get at the array position [1] does this make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharePoint 2010 Get Current Username / Logged in User](http://yalla.itgroove.net/2011/12/sharepoint-2010-get-current-username-logged-in-user/)

check this StackExchange answer as well 
[Get the current user interacting with a site workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26583/get-the-current-user-interacting-with-a-site-workflow)

if you are wanting to get the current user when you log in you can try something like this

```
SPWeb webSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(SPContext);
SPUser spUser = webSite.CurrentUser;
string strUserName = spUser.LoginName;
```

using this line below will return the **OriginatorUser however if you are not logged in as Admin you will get the System Account UserName**

```
//This give the Login name e.g <domain>\<name>  
workflowProperties.OriginatorUser.LoginName;
```

** Note ** I noticed that in your code you are trying to get / assign user twice
you should only need this line if you decide to use your code

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
```

Comment: I tried this and its its throwing an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object "

Comment: Which line.. if it's the first line then change `Context` to `SPContext`

Comment: Am not why it is not working in my environment. I referred the above website and am trying the same function but it returns Null.

Comment: can you get a hold of someone on your end to make sure you have proper access rights ..?

Answer (score 1):

its seem to work :

```
 SPUser user = this.workflowProperties.OriginatorUser;
```

`RunWithElevatedPrivileges` gives you `system account` privileges in addition to the privileges you would get with a reverto call.

is that code executed on [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) method ??

**Here is a another trick that i found :**

```
string ModifiedbyUserName = Convert.ToString(workflowProperties.Item.GetFormattedValue("Modified By"));
```

see this : [logged-in user in workflow](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/08/how-to-get-currently-logged-in-user-in.html)

Helps it helps!!

Comment: No, it's not executed on SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges function. I have even tried this option   SPUser user = this.workflowProperties.OriginatorUser; and its still giving me system account. Am logging as a different users but not as System Account.

Comment: If I execute the code in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges then its giving me the username as Null.

Comment: SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
              SPUser user = this.workflowProperties.OriginatorUser;
              string pmName = user.Name;                              
            });

Comment: Thanks for update Jigs. I tried this procedure too but ModifiedbyUserName value is null. I tried to debug the application.